# How to learn computer science the right way

Tags: programming-languages, software-engineering, java

I looked through the sites and this seems to be the best place to ask this question. I am sure it has been asked 10000 times but I am looking for a tailored answer to me and my situation. I currently work as a project manager for a startup. I have a working knowledge into many different fields ranging from HTML, CSS, PHP, JS, MySQL, Server Administration, Marketing, SEO, Etc. I have been working in the web development industry for the last 10 years, I started when I was 11. I have associates level education but no BCS. I don't have the time right now to pursue that as much as I would love to in my current situation(newborn son) and my wife is pursuing her eduction currently. I knew all these language but I don't really know them. I wanna truly understand them, why they work the way they do and how I can master them. This is more of a personal desire then one driven by money, as they most likely wont affect my career. I really would like to learn a new language.

I have about 3-5 hours every week night while I have my son and my wife is in school to study at home. I can't really afford college or guarantee that I will have that time available to make that commitment so I would like to have a no pressure solution. I have completed a lot of treehouse and didn't find much of a challenge.  The courses really didnt drive into the languages either and teach me anything new.

I am looking to start learning things like computer logic, but I need some pointers of where to start and what terms to search to find this education info. After I truly understand the inner workings of a computer from the microprocessor to ram to harddrive to interpreter to etc, I would like to learn a new programming language. My current PHP skills arent great, and its more of a working knowledge then understand so treat me as a new programmer.

To sum things up

- Can I have some recommendations of key concepts to learn for new software engineers
- If anyone can provide good education sources, please do so
- I would like some recommendations of languages to learn that are in demand and are new, and arent going anywhere anytime soon. From my current research it looks like Java or C# are my best options. Anything I should know about those, any assume the previous questions apply to them.
- I am willing to pay for this

Comment: 1) This is not about computer science, but about programming. 2) This is far too broad for a single questoin. 3) SE is not suitable to negotiating business relations.

Comment: Why have you rejected [programmers.SE]? As far as I can tell, your question would fit there much better. Should I migrate it?

Comment: @Raphael As you say, it's too broad. No point migrating it to somewhere else that will just close it for reasons we can already see here.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, most of the things you are talking about fall under the category of *programming*, rather than *computer science*. Programming is a useful tool for computer scientists, and indeed some computer scientists study programming, but it programming barely scratches the surface of what computer science is about.

Why not try a free online course, such as one offered by [coursera](https://www.coursera.org/courses?categories=cs-programming,cs-systems,cs-theory)? There are many many courses, from programming to theory to machine learning to software engineering. All are free and typically the standard of quality is extremely high.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Exactly what I was looking for. Its kind of confusing for new people to stack overflow's network to figure out where to post things as there's so many places. If you have any more links it would be great. Also, I want to learn about how programs work from the hardware to the end product to become a better programmer, I thought this would be a suitable place. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things that apply to any field of programming

- Object Oriented Design and Design Patterns
- Algorithms and Data Structures

There is a wealth of free resources to learn now a days. For instance both MIT and Stanford offer free resources online where you can watch video recordings of the lectures.